# reshaping by index with melt and acast

Tags: r, reshape2

This should be a simple exercise with `reshape2` package in R but somehow I'm not seeing it.

Imagine I have data:

`df <- data.frame(A = rnorm(4), B = rnorm(4))`

which looks like:

```
       A          B

1  2.3729531 -0.9252266
2  0.9848229 -0.1152347
3  2.1234409  0.9035180
4 -0.5771637  1.2755104
```

`long_form <- melt(df)`

which looks like

```
  variable      value
1        A  2.3729531
2        A  0.9848229
3        A  2.1234409
4        A -0.5771637
5        B -0.9252266
6        B -0.1152347
7        B  0.9035180
8        B  1.2755104
```

How do I transform `long_form` back into `df`?

I can do this by adding another column first,

`long_form = data.frame(id = c(1:4, 1:4), long_form)
dcast(long_form, id ~ variable)`

and then drop the id column to recover `df`; but it just seems like I should be able to do this without explicitly adding an id column to index the replicate A's and B's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
dcast(melt(df), 1:4 ~ variable)
```

which is somewhat shorter.

Comment: nice. Is there something less than `1:dim(subset(long_form, variable=="A"))[1]` if I don't know the number of replicates?

Comment: You can always do simple stuff like `dcast(long_form, seq_along(df[,1])~variable)[,-1]` or `dcast(long_form, 1:(nrow(long_form)/length(unique(long_form$variable)))~variable)[,-1]`

Comment: @Dinre that supposes we know `df`, in which case we don't need an inverse transform.

Comment: Sorry... accidentally hit enter when typing... wasn't finished producing the whole comment.

Comment: hmm.. a bit shorter: `dcast(long_form, 1:table(long_form$variable)[1] ~ variable)`

Comment: @cboettig see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16502889/1478381) for an alternative answer to your comment question

Comment: @SimonO101 thanks. Though the call to `ave` in that example appears a bit counter-intuitive.  I feel like @eddi's approach is a bit more transparent; (though `table` isn't particularly satisfactory in that regard either)

Comment: @cboettig eh? I didn't post the link as an alternative to eddi's approach (which is exactly what I would do). I psoted it becuase after eddi answered your question you asked another question in the comments about creating the ID sequence if you don't know the replicates beforehand. i.e. if you don't know 1:4

Comment: @cboettig - here's another approach for the enumeration - `seq_len(nrow(long_form)/nlevels(long_form[,1]))` (assuming you have factors)

Comment: @SimonO101 Yup, I realize that.  I think my use of `table` in my comment above is a more concise answer to deal with not knowing the number of replicates (it also makes it relatively clear we are assuming A and B have the same number of replicates by just using table()[1]).  But still not completely transparent.